# Node.js example native extension

Tags: node.js, native

I am not able to run the easiest type of Node.js native extension, a Hello World, and I don't know why.

I am using the example here: http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world

`node-gyp` runs just fine, but when I try to `require` it in node, I get an error:

```
  Error: invalid argument
    at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at repl:1:13
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21)
    at repl.js:190:20
    at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:87:5)
    at Interface. (repl.js:182:12)
```

What is this, and how can I debug errors like this when using native extensions?

Comment: The code is in the example I linked above. If it does not compile, then either my system is not set up correctly or I'm doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the example now works, after I have wrapped the `init` section in an `extern "C"` block.

Everything is good now.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are by any chance following this example: https://www.cloudkick.com/blog/2010/aug/23/writing-nodejs-native-extensions/

Do have in mind that the initialization function you give to `NODE_MODULE` **must not be `static`**! It appears that the introspection library or other mechanisms that Node.js uses to register your module, don't support reading (the names of) static functions in C.

Hope this helps everyone having similar issues!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/olalonde/node-notify

There is everything explained in the readme.